# Will too many characters be overwhelming?

Tags: characters

So I have multiple stories running in the same universe, and I want a Arc that includes all the main people from each of the stories my worry is that this will become to confusing and may overload the reader.

This is a rough idea of how many characters I’ll have from each story

Story 1- 4 Main Characters, 3 Semi-main Characters & 2 Plot Characters

Story 2- 2 Main Characters, 2 Semi-main Characters & 3 Plot Characters

Story 3- 3 Main Characters, 2 Semi-Main Characters

Story 4- 2 Main Characters, 1 Semi-Main Characters

That means I’ll have:
11 Main Characters
8 Semi-Main Characters
5 Plot Characters
Which means I’ll have a total of 24 characters that the reader would have to remember

Comment: Hi, welcome to writing.se! Take the [tour] and visit the [help] for more information. Please check out the linked question and see if that answers your question. If you don't think it is a duplicate you can [edit] your question to make it clear how they are different. Good luck and happy writing!

Comment: By "story" you mean a short story, or a novel-sized book?

Comment: With 24 people, at least you can give each one a name that begins with a different letter of the alphabet.

Comment: Ah, if you are asking about the number of total acceptable characters, you can probably have 50 named characters in a full series and still be okay if you write them memorably, and this would be a duplicate question. However, if you are asking specifically about POV characters, this is not a duplicate question, and I would never write more than 3 said POV characters. If you are new to writing, I don't recommend more than 2. Every time you change POV, you lose momentum, and you have to catch the reader up again. Ideally, the reader will be sad to leave a POV, but excited to return to another.

Comment: I did mean more of a POV thing, thank you for the help